# Problems with unicode in R

Tags: r, unicode

I am having problems with printing unicode characters in R. Initially the problems started with me trying to plot some custom labels with ggplot, but I have found out that this problem runs deeper.

For example, the letter **đ** is represented with unicode code U+0100. This means that if I type

```
"\u0100"
```

in the console, I should get **đ** printed as output, right? However, this is not what happens. Instead, as the output I get:

```
<U+0100>
```

I don't understand why this is happening since my encoding is set to UTF-8. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

I tried using the following function:

```
stri_escape_unicode("<U+0100>")
```

but I just get the same output as before. Any help would be appreciated! I am using Macbook Pro from 2013.

Comment: I can't confirm your issue; firstly, U+0100 should be ["LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH MACRON"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0100/index.htm); secondly `ss <- "abc\u0100ef"; print(ss)` prints just fine `[1] "abcĀef"` on my MacBook; lastly, to *escape* a unicode character you would write `stringi::stri_escape_unicode("\u0100")`; I'm not sure why you're trying to do that though.

Comment: Note: your encoding is your encoding **within the program**. Encoding of console could be an other. Console could maybe not support Unicode, or just font doesn't support it. First step to debug. try to write a file and check if in the file the encoding is correct.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake for the wrong unicode code for đ, it should be U+0111. In any case, I think something is still wrong on my side, but I can't figure out what. When I run the code you wrote (`ss <- "abc\u0100ef"; print(ss)`), the output I get is `[1] "abc<U+0100>ef"`. I'm trying to do this because I need to plot some unicade characters with ggplot, but it's not working and I have found out that the problem is not only appearing within ggplot, but also when I try to simply print the character in the console. How can I see the encoding of my console?